# How to read and write file in meteor.js?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Is it possible to read or find from MongoDB and save it to  files for backup purpose, and read from files and insert it back to the database for restore purpose?

Answer (score 0):

For backup purpose you can use regular mongo tools : [`mongodump`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongodump/) and [`mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongorestore/).

You would need to setup a CRON job or something similar to backup your data every now and then.

You could also use a [Mongo as a service provider](https://www.google.fr/search?q=mongo%20as%20a%20service) that will automatically take care of that for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to read and write file for backup and restore purpose, because mongodump and mongorestore will backup and restore the whole database. But sometimes I want to backup and restore just some collection only.

Comment: You can specify which collections you want to `mongodump` using a command line parameter : http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--collection

Comment: Thanks,but how can I backup and restore the specific collections for the client of Meteor.js app?